# Getting Azure VM OS name using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure

I have been trying to get the VM OS name from Microsoft Azure using PowerShell.

I think I am very close to the solution but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

This is the command that I am using to get the VM details:

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName TEST -Name VF-Test1 | Select OsType
```

The answer I get is just blank.

When running the following command:

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName TEST -Name VF-Test1
```

I get all the details that belong to that VM.

Comment: Non-programming related questions are best suited for http://serverfault.com

Comment: @user2956653 you can use (get-azurermvm -ResourceGroupName jason -Name vm1).StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType to get the type.

Answer (score 9):

The `osType` property lives inside `$_.StorageProfile.osDisk`

```bsh
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName TEST -Name VMNAME |
    Format-Table Name, @{l='osType';e={$_.StorageProfile.osDisk.osType}}

Name      osType
------    ------
VMNAME    Windows
```

Use https://resources.azure.com to explore the object representation when in doubt, or pipe to [`Show-Object`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PowerShellCookbook/1.3.6), like i did below.

[image: Show-Object]

Comment: Thank you for the answer! it worked like a treat. and the website seems very useful thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get resource groups' VMs by `Get-AzureRmVM` and classic VMs by `Get-AzureVM`. Both of the returning values of the two cmdlets contain OS type properties but in different paths.

- For the cmdlet `Get-AzureRmVM`, the OS type property path is `$vm.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType`
- For the cmdlet `Get-AzureVM`, the OS type property path is `$vm.VM.OSVirtualHardDisk.OS`

There exists a sample code about fetching Azure VM OS Type here: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/How-to-retrieve-Azure-5a3d3751

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-AzVM -name SERVERNAME | select name, @{n="OS";E={$_.StorageProfile.OsDisk.OsType}}, @{n="Offer";E={$_.StorageProfile.ImageReference.offer}} , @{n="SKU";E={$_.StorageProfile.ImageReference.sku}}, @{n="Publisher";E={$_.StorageProfile.ImageReference.Publisher}}
```

RESULT:

[image]